# A confused descriptive paragraph

Tags: meaning-in-context

I saw a post on Reddit, I knew every meaning of words but I can't get what process of action they were describing. Below is the post they put.

> I had to call my boss for help with a machine that would not cooperate. We are talking as I am tightening a bolt and my slips. I split my knuckle open and called the machine every 4-letter word.

Specifically, the problem for me to understand is in what is *bolt* and *slips* and *splitting knuckle open*.

Comment: This is a bolt: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-4-in-x-1-1-2-in-Galvanized-Hex-Bolt-15-Pack-80470/203151676

Answer (score 1):

It looks like he made a grammatical error when writing the post on Reddit. What it was meant to say was

> "I was tightening a bolt and I `slipped`. I split my knuckle open and called the machine every 4-letter word"

By "splitting" his "knuckle" open, he meant he had cut open his knuckle and injured it.

Comment: No, he probably meant *and my hand slips*

Comment: Slipped as he is talking about something that happened in the past.

Comment: @UniversalLink No, the sentence is phrased in the present tense. "We *are* talking," "I *am* tightening." The same present tense should be used: *slips*. So, *my hand slips* is the only correction that makes sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford "I had", speaking in the past tense. The statement is a mix of past and present tense but he defined it as present tense via the "I had" at the beginning of the post.

Comment: @UniversalLink There are three sentences. The second sentence (which starts *We* ***are*** *talking*) is the one in question.